# Promise Arrangment and Syntax

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone could clarify the following.

What is the difference between this:

```
function(arg).then((ret) => {
   anotherFunc(ret);
}).catch(error)
```

and this:

```
function(arg).then((ret => {
   anotherFunc(ret);
})).catch(error)
```

Difference is the brackets when the promise is returned.

Comment: Nothing. `(x)` is the same as `x` (as is `((x))`, `(((x)))` etc). `(...)` is the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) which is used to change the order of evaluation when you work with nested expressions. There is also `(ret)` and `ret` but that's actually something different: If an arrow function only has a single parameter you can omit the parenthesis around them.

Comment: First one has brackets around the parameter. These brackets are optional if there is only one parameter. The second one doesn't have them but has brackets around the whole arrow function. These brackets are even more optional - in the latter case, it's the grouping operator as Felix Kling says. Placing a single set of grouping brackets around a single expression doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example looks strange. I think your question has to do more with arrow functions syntax. If arrow functions have one argument, you can skip the parentheses. For example .

```
const logA = a => console.log(a);
const logB = (b) => console.log(b);
```

As you see, logA argument doesn't have (), logB argument does have (b). They both work exactly the same way, just a syntax preference.

```
function(arg).then((ret) => {
   anotherFunc(ret);
}).catch(error)
```

OR

```
  function(arg).then(ret => {
       anotherFunc(ret);
    }).catch(error)
```

Are the same.

Comment: The second example would be `logC = (c => console.log(c))`

Comment: I thought he meant  the parentheses confusion. You usually don't write the code that way)

Comment: I don't disagree - I definitely haven't seen this used anywhere. But it's still valid code, even if meaningless.